# How do you return the list of unique values in dataframe and not the index value of the list when aggregating in R?

Tags: r

Given the below dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(seq(1:4),rep(letters[seq(1:3)],4)))
```

`X1 X2
 1  a
 2  b
 3  c
 4  a
 1  b
 2  c
 3  a
 4  b
 1  c
 2  a
 3  b
 4  c`

I would like to summarize unique X2s by X1. For example,

`1 a,b,c
 2 b,c,a
 3 c,a,b
 4 a,b,c`

I am very close. I use the following code:

```
'summary <- aggregate(df$X2, list(df$X1),FUN=unique)`
```

which produces

`Group.1     X
       1 1,2,3
       2 2,3,1
       3 3,1,2
       4 1,2,3`

(the index of the list). What is the most efficient way to get my desired result?

I am certain there is an easy solution and I've tried searching, but I must not be using the correct search terms. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Perhaps your main problem is that X2 is stored as a factor rather than as a string. If you use `df <- data.frame(cbind(seq(1:4),rep(letters[seq(1:3)],4)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`, then your code may produce what you want.

Comment: Or to simplify @lmo 's solution  `aggregate(df$X2, by=list(df$X1), function(x) unique(as.character(x)))`

Comment: Wow, thanks. I see you just wrote your own function and basically changing from factor to character. I get it and it worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `toString` to `paste` the elements

```
aggregate(X2~X1, unique(df), toString )
```

Or if we need to keep it as `list`

```
aggregate(X2~X1, transform(unique(df), X2 = as.character(X2)), list)
```

---

As the OP also mentioned the efficient approach

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df))[, .(X2 = toString(X2)), by = X1]
```

---

Regarding the creation of `data.frame`, it is easier, compact and error-free way to do without using `cbind` with `data.frame`.  The main reason is that `cbind` converts to a `matrix` and `matrix` can have only a single class.  So, if there is a single `character` column or elements, all the elements are converted to `character`.  With `as.data.frame`, by default the `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`, so the columns are converted to `factor` class.

```
df <- data.frame(X1= 1:4, X2= rep(letters[1:3],4), stringsAsFactors= FALSE)
```

The above code gets the intended output.  Note that `seq` is not needed when we use `:`

Comment: I think that you are leaving off the `unique` part. The sample data provided has no repetitions, but if there were repetitions,  your code would not eliminate them.

Comment: I did indeed ask for efficiency in order to help me be a better R programmer. I looked up the package data.table. This seems like it will come in handy. If I understand correctly you are taking the unique values of the converted df to a data table. You are going over all rows and I get the by=X1. Will you please explain what this part is doing, `.(X2 = toString(X2))` particularly the period in front? The other portion is basically saying you are converting X2 to a string instead of a factor, right?

Comment: @ScottHunter  You can change the `.` with `list` ie. `list(X2 = toString(X2))` and `toString` is just `paste(X2, collapse=", ")`  We are taking the `unique` values as I found that you are using `unique` in the code.